# "That they declared to be~" Vs. "That they said to be~"

Tags: word-difference

I see they can use either ways as follows:

> They declared that to be~
>
> They said that to be~

But, somehow, when you change the sentences' structure like those of title, "That they said to be~" just gave me 0 google results. Why is that?

Comment: Never rely on Google hits for anything authoritative. (Google should only be used as a reference to sites that *are* authoritative.)

Comment: @JasonBassford So, do you imply that "That they said to be~" is a correct and natural way to use? I'm not a native, so I don't have any confidence with it.

Comment: This is grammatical: *The answer that they said to be wrong was actually right.* I would rephrase it to simply *the answer that they said* ***was*** *wrong was actually right*, as that sounds more natural, but there's nothing actually wrong with the former.

Comment: If Google gives no results for "that they said to be", I think Google is having a bit of a bad day. That combination of words comes up a fair amount, I believe.

Comment: I checked, and the only result is this question. Weird. "That they declared to be" has healthy results, though.